How to distribute iOS app to only external groups on TestFlight?
I want to distribute the app to only external groups and not the internal groups. But every time I create and upload a build by choosing "Testflight and AppStore", the build compulsorily gets distributed to the internal groups as well, which I don't want to

I don't think it's possible. Whenever you upload a build to App Store Connect, it's immediately available to developers, it's by design.

If you remove access to the app to the internal tester in App Store Connect, then they will not get the TestFlight build, but if they are a developer for the app then they will have access to the app, otherwise they cannot develop it...

You can't do this, Internal testers have more access than external testers by default. Internal testers are and should be trusted members.
